# Flutter: Native Appbar or custom Appbar? Which is better?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I'm customizing my AppBar in flutter and I'm trying to obtain a result like this:

I liked the idea of ​​using the appbar widget for the many features it has by default (adaptive width etc...), but I think the customization is too constraining due to the obligatory use of the 3 attributes: leading, text, action.

what do you recommend? the appbar widget or a custom Container or similar?

thank you all.

Comment: Use AppBar widget

Comment: Depends on the requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a design like this i recomend you to use a custom app bar using Container it will be more simple and faster for you to design it

Answer (score 1):

If you want, use a `Column` in body. After adding the first container, you can shape the container as in the photo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry use **AppBar()** it's simple and you can build the same design with it .